# using GKAgents to move sprites from left to right and back

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, contacts, skphysicsbody, gameplay-kit

I'm looking for a way to move a `GKAgent` from left to right across a screen.  The agent is connected to a `GKEntity` and I've created two further agents, called "leftWall" and "rightWall".  For each agent, there is a matching sprite node with a unique name. I've tried to use `SKPhysicsContact` in my main `GameScene` to pass a new target agent (e.g. if it makes contact with the leftNode, pass the rightNode's name) to the agent moving through the screen.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node
        let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node

        if nodeA!.name == "leftWall" {
            entityManager.contactWithWall("rightWall", nodeName: (nodeB?.name)!)
        }
```

To get to the moving agent, I have a class in between which holds an array of entities.

```
class EntityManager {
    var entities = Set<GKEntity>()
.
.
.
func contactWithWall (newWallName: String, nodeName: String) {
        for entity in entities {
            if let spriteComponent = entity.componentForClass(SpriteComponent.self) {
                if spriteComponent.node.name == nodeName 
                    entity.targetWallEntityName = newWallName
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

From in the moving `GKAgent`, I look up the agent for the wall that corresponds `targetWallEntityName` (which is a String variable) and pass this to a 'seek `GKGoal`.'  This basically works except that when I set up a number of agents, passing a new `targetWallEntityName` doesn't just affect the agent that has made contact with the left or right wall, it affects all agents.  The results is all agents are oscillating in the screen, responding to the physics contact from the agents closest to the two walls. Any ideas how to resolve this?  Should I try to pass the target to the entity first, before sending it to it's agent?

Comment: Does each sprite node have a unique name?

Comment: Yes! They are all unique. The names of the walls are "leftWall" and "rightWall," respectively.  The moving agents have names like "node1," "node2," etc. The difficulty seems to be all the agents are being passed the same String variable instead of just the one that has made contact with the wall. Do you know a way to select just one entity's agent?

Comment: I suggest you set a breakpoint at `entity.targetWallEntityName = ...` to make sure that only one entity is being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `0x141E`. I've traced the problem to a difference between the scaling of one `spriteNode` and its corresponding `physicsBody`. Using `SKPhysics` to trigger a new agent to seek works fine. For some reason though, when one node triggers a collision too frequently (because of it's body's size in this case), all the agents in the game seem to take over the seek target from this one agent, and the game enters a chaotic state.